# watching value of inner element in directive

Tags: angularjs

How can I scope some inner element's value to an arbitrary variable and watch for its changes?

```
//search.html
<div>
   <input type="search" class="input-medium search-query" />
</div>

angular.module('search',[])
   .directive "searchBar", ->
      restrict: "E"
      templateUrl: 'search.html'
      replace: true
```

Now I'd like to $watch for input's value change ('keyup') and access (get and set) current value from "outside". Can I have some arbitrary attribute and access it, like:

```
<div>
  <search-bar value='{{searchTerm}}' />
</div>
```

*I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of `searchTerm`  inside your directives linking function.

```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // input element
        var input= angular.element(element.children()[0]);
        input.bind('keyup', function(){
            scope.searchTerm = input.val();
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer will create a "searchTerm" variable in the parent scope. This is unreliable, because if you put your directive in another scope (say a form) it will not be accessible outside of that form. What you should do is create "searchTerm" where you need it, and then pass it to "searchBar". If you are not using isolated scope for "searchBar" then you don't have to even pass it. If you do use isolated scope then passing would looks something like this.

```
angular.module('search',[])
   .directive("searchBar", function () {
      restrict: "E"
      scope: {
          searchTermInside: '=searchTerm'
      },
      templateUrl: 'search.html'
      replace: true});
```

And you use the directive like so:

```
<search-bar searchTerm="searchTermOutside" />
```

And in template

```
//search.html
<div>
   <input type="search" ng-model="searchTermInside" class="input-medium search-query" />
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, however how would you handle the update on `keyup` in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by keyup? Are you looking to track changes in the searchTerm? You just put a `scope.$watch('searchTermOutside', function ()...` where you need it.

Comment: It was just part of the OP's question. I was just curious how you would handle it in your solution.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you are not the OP. Yeah your solution is still valid if you need to track an event. But one doesn't need to listen to keyup to get updates on that model, angular just works its magic =)

Comment: Agreed, magic is the best way to put it. Directives are something I still need to wrap my head around. My answer was a quick and dirty solution.